# Sphere object deformation after changing position of sphere

Tags: three.js

I have two sphere objects on the scene. Both of them been made with default position (scene center). There is no problem when objects are in the middle, however when I want to move one to the right and second to the left, strange deformation has a place. When spheres moving away from the center on X axis they seems to be more squeezed on Y axis. It is kind of "FishEye" lens effect. Is it possible that some default cameras value is interfering to make such a result? FOV value does not bring solution for that, and I did not find information about camera lens properties. What is wrong with that?

I have tried to play with Vector3 as a position provider and spheres has the same result.
I have tried object.position.set(vector3) with no result. 
Also object.position.copy(vector3) gave the same result.
Trying translate position without animation gave the same result. 
Playing with FOV parameter in camera object also did not solve the problem.

```
// init
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1,10000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//creating sphere

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(6, 16, 16);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true});
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

//earth

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 16, 16);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff, wireframe: true});
var earth = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);



scene.add(sphere, earth);
camera.position.z = 10;



var animation = function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    update();
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

var update = function(){
   earth.rotation.y +=0.001;
   sphere.rotation.y -=0.001;
   sphere.rotation.x -=0.001;
   sphere.position.x +=0.001;

}
```

I expect to move sphere.postion.x -=1; and earth.position.x+=1; without squeezing and deformation of spheres on Y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for taking the time to take the tour, and for including your code.

The fish-eye effect is likely being caused by your camera defintion:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1,10000);
```

The `100` is the FOV (Field of View) for your camera, and is quite wide. In a `PerspectiveCamera`, the wider your FOV, the more distortion you'll see for objects closer to the edges. Try setting it lower to get a more natural effect.

Do some searches for "Perspective Distortion" and you should find a host of articles on why it happens and how to mitigate it. For starters, here's the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_distortion_(photography) which has a nice animation of changing the FOV for an image of a house.

Comment: TheJim01 - thank you for right answer and clue to deeper understanding of how perspective lens works! Now I solve the problem. I just changed for smaller radius of objects and calibrated cameras FOV. Works perfectly. Thank you again!